Is there any API endpoint provided by github - "to get unique users who downloaded released asset"?
Github provides very good support for developer API endpoints. We have a requirement like - how many of unique users downloaded a particular release asset. I know, there is download_count in one of API's response, but we want unique users only.
I tried to look into gh-api documents but I could not find it.
Seems like there no API endpoint provided by github, does anyone have a workaround for this?

GitHub does not provide analytics for unique user downloads. To get these you will need to use something like Google Analytics and self-host the assets and a web-page with trackable download links. You could use S3 for hosting, for example.
